# Redirect www.mysite.com/index.html to www.mysite.com/ with .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I wish to redirect www.mysite.com/index.html

to

www.mysite.com/

but I do not wish to redirect all addresses with index.html like

www.mysite.com/folder/index.html

to

www.mysite.com/folder/

So, just to redirect first index.html page to root of site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add the following to the .htaccess file in the root folder of www.mysite.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect html pages to the root domain
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]
```