# How to redirect index.html to /

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, redirect

How can I redirect every index.html file to /
For example redirect this URL: https://www.example.com/contact/index.html to https://www.example.com/contact/

Note: I don't want to redirect to the root, I want to redirect to the same directory just remove the index.html
Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect www.mysite.com/index.html to www.mysite.com/ with .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545243/redirect-www-mysite-com-index-html-to-www-mysite-com-with-htaccess-file)

Comment: Hi @esqew I saw that and it's a different question. I don't want to redirect to the root. I want to redirect to the same directory just remove index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect www.mysite.com/index.html to www.mysite.com/ with .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545243/redirect-www-mysite-com-index-html-to-www-mysite-com-with-htaccess-file)

Comment: Hi @it4Astuces I saw that and it's a different question. I don't want to redirect to the root. I want to redirect to the same directory just remove index.html

Comment: @Ardian Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481028/removing-the-index-html-from-url

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Apache the following lines in *.htaccess* file under the */contact* folder will do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html$   %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/folder/$1/        [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.html$   %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/folder/    [R=301,L]
```

where *folder* is *contact* in your example.

Earlier I suggested using the following rule for a shortcut of the above two:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$   %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/folder/$1       [R=301,L]
```

However, this has an unwanted side-effect of redirecting say something like https://www.example.com/contact/myindex.html to https://www.example.com/contact/my

**Note:** Please be careful not to cause redirection "loops" like:

```
xxx/index.html -> xxx/ -> xxx/index.html -> xxx/ ...
```

Comment: Hi @Fedon Kadifeli Thank you very much for your answer.
What if the URL is like this:

https://www.example.com/contact/page-1/index.html and to redirect to  https://www.example.com/contact/page-1

The code that you provided is returning https://www.example.com/contact/page-1/index.html to https://www.example.com/contact/

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? In my environment it works as expected.

Comment: Hi @Fedon Kadifeli

Yes, that is correct. The redirect is going from https://www.example.com/contact/page-1/index.html to https://www.example.com/contact so it is skipping one directory.

Comment: Can you paste the relevant part of the .htaccess file? 
(Also, check web server log to see that the redirection action is being taken and not the web browser cache is shown.)

Comment: Hi @Fedon Kadifeli
Only the code you have provided is in .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html$   %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/$1/       [R=301,L]

Still the redirect is going from example.com/contact/page-1/index.html to example.com/contact so it is skipping one directory.

Thank you!

Comment: @ardian : Assuming that you have put your _.htaccess_ file under your `/contact` web folder and not on your _root_ web folder, you should replace the `RewriteRule` line with something like: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.html$   %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/contact/$1/       [R=301,L]`

Comment: @ardian : Please note that the above will not work for _example.com/contact/index.html_ though (because of the "/" preceding index.html in the matching side. For this, I suggest you add a second rule like: `RewriteRule ^index.html$   %{CONTEXT_PREFIX}/contact/    [R=301,L]`